# When is Stone-Čech compactification the same as one-point compactification?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, compactification, alexandroff-compactification

For the space $\omega_1$ (with the order topology) we have $\beta\omega_1=\omega_1+1$ (or $\beta[0,\omega_1)=[0,\omega_1]$, if you prefer this notation), i.e., it is an example of a space for which
[Stone-Čech compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone-Cech_compactification)
and [one-point compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-point_compactification)
(a.k.a. Alexandroff compactification) coincide. (See, for example, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171951/how-many-points-does-stone-ech-compactification-add/171954#171954) and [this blog](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2009/10/11/the-first-uncountable-ordinal/).)

> Is there some known characterization of topological spaces such that Stone-Čech compactification $\beta X$ and one-point compactification $\omega X$ are the same?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The following is from a problem in Engelking (Problem 3.12.16, p.234), and it credited to E. Hewitt, *Certain generalizations of the Weierstrass approximation theorem*, Duke Math. J. 14 (1947), 419-427:

> ...[F]or every Tychonoff space $X$ the following conditions are equivalent
>
> 1. The space $X$ has a unique (up to equivalence) compactification.
> 2. The space $X$ is compact or $| \beta X \setminus X | = 1$.
> 3. If two closed subsets of $X$ are completely separated, then at least one of them is compact.

Comment: Thanks a lot! In case they are useful for someone, here are links to the Hewitt's paper: [projecteuclid](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077474139), [doi:10.1215/S0012-7094-47-01435-X](http://dx.doi.org/10.1215/S0012-7094-47-01435-X), [MR](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0021662), [Zentralblatt](http://www.zentralblatt-math.org/zmath/en/search/?q=an:0029.30302&format=complete). (I have looked in Engelking for places mentioning Alexandroff compactifications, so I missed this one.)

Comment: These spaces are called "almost compact" in some texts. I believe that this is also an exercise in Rings of continuous functions.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma you're right: Exercise 6J in Gillman-Jerison is called *almost compact spaces* and it says that the following conditions are equivalent:
(1) Of any two disjoint zero-sets in $X$, at least one is compact.
(2) $|\beta X-X|\le1$.
(3) $X\subset T$ implies $f(X)\subset f(T)$.
(4) Every embedding of $X$ is a C${}^*$-embedding.
(5) Every embedding of $X$ is a C-embedding.
(6) The only compactification of $X$ is $\beta X$.
(7) Every embedding of any continuous image of $X$ is a C-embedding.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: You could add (8): The space $X$ admits a unique uniformity. See Chapter II, Exercise 11 (c) in J. R. Isbell, *Uniform spaces*.

Comment: It's worth noting that the first uncountable ordinal is an example of a non-compact space satisfying the conditions above.