# Minimal and maximal unitization of $C^{*}$ algebras

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Is there  a  non unital $C^{*}$  algebra  $A$  for  which the  multiplier algebra $M(A)$ is  isomorphic  to the  minimal unitization $\tilde{A}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For separable $A$, it is never true: in 3.2.12 in Pedersen's C*-Algebras and their Automorphisms, it is shown that for non-unital $A$, $M(A)$ is always non-separable.

In the commutative case, you have $A=C_0(X)$ for some locally compact Hausdorff $X$, and $M(A)=C^b(X)=C(\beta X)$. So in this case the answer is yes for those $X$ with unique compactification; see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/335830/when-is-stone-%C4%8Cech-compactification-the-same-as-one-point-compactification) for some details on those spaces.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. What about for $A$ commutative but not necessarily separable?

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: thank you so much for this edited version