# Does the Stone-Čech compactification respect subspaces?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, compactness

That is, is it true that if $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces (assume they are Tychonoff, if necessary), with $X \subseteq Y$, then $\beta X$ is homeomorphic to a subspace of $\beta Y$? If so, how does one prove this? If not, what would be a counter-example?

My lecturer has asked us to come up with questions for the exam in 4 days. I've been trying to prove this, but juggling all the various spaces and topologies is making my head hurt, and I'm hitting so many dead ends that I'm beginning to think it's not true.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The inclusion $X\hookrightarrow Y\hookrightarrow\beta Y$ induces a map $\beta X\to\beta Y$. Are you asking if this induced map might be not injective, or if there is no injection $\beta X\to\beta Y$ at all?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $X=\mathbb N$ and $Y=\mathbb N^*$, the one-point compactification of $\mathbb N$, then $\beta Y\approx \mathbb N^*$, which is countable. However, $\beta\mathbb N$ is not countable, hence there cannot be an injection into $\beta\mathbb N^*$

Comment: Thank you very much Stephan, that's really helpful. I was actually just thinking about $\mathbb{N}$ in relation to $\mathbb{R}$. Would I be right in thinking that $\mathbb{R}$ is a circle, hence metrizable, so therefore incapable of being a superspace of $\beta \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb R^*$? That is a circle, right. You can also compare the local bases: The circle is first-countable, but $\beta\mathbb N$ is not.

Comment: I mean $\beta \mathbb{R}$ is a circle. Thanks again! Actually, while I have your attention, are there any reasonable conditions that you know of that we can place on $X$ so that we get this inclusion? Perhaps if $X$ is dense in $Y$?

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea what $\beta\mathbb R$ looks like. But if you are sure that it is homeomorphic to a circle, then you can use this reasoning.

Comment: I'm not sure in hindsight. My logic was faulty.

Comment: @TheoBendit: Seems like you can use the universal property of the $\beta$-functor to show that $\beta\mathbb R$ can not be homeomorphic to a circle. Note that $\mathbb R$ is homeomorphic to $(0,1)$ and the embedding of $(0,1)$ into $[0,1]$ can not be extended to a map $S^1\to[0,1]$.

Comment: A sufficient condition for the inclusion of a subspace $X$ of a space $Y$ to extend to an inclusion $\beta X \to \beta Y$ is that $X$ be $C^\ast$-embedded in $Y$: every bounded continuous function on $X$ extends to a bounded continuous function on $Y$. In that case $\beta X$ can be identified with the closure of $X$ in $\beta Y$. // Regarding the discussion of $\beta\mathbb{R}$: it is as big as $\beta \mathbb{N}$, so has cardinality $2^{\frak{c}}$. However it is quite different, for example it is connected.

Comment: @Theo: $\beta\Bbb R$ is definitely not a circle: its cardinality is $2^\mathfrak{c}$, while that of a circle is only $\mathfrak{c}$. See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/96057/12042) for details.

Answer (score 8):

A natural follow-up question here is "what does the Stone-Čech compactification respect?" A general answer is that $\beta$ is [left adjoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_functors) to the inclusion functor from compact Hausdorff spaces to topological spaces, and as a left adjoint it consequently preserves all [colimits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(category_theory)#Colimits). In particular, it preserves disjoint unions and [coequalizers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coequalizer) (hence [epimorphisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epimorphism)). But subspaces are related to limits rather than colimits (since they're related to monomorphisms rather than epimorphisms) so one shouldn't expect a left adjoint to preserve them.