# Sufficient proof that $[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ contains only its cluster points.

Tags: general-topology

I was working on the following problem:

Find an example of a nonempty countable
set A such that every cluster point of A is in A and every point in A is
a cluster point of A.

And came up with this:

A set $U:=[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ contains all of its cluster points and every member of $U$ is a cluster point of $U$.

Proof:

- $[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ is closed in $\mathbb{Q}$.
- A set is closed iff it contains all of its cluster points.
- Since $[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ is closed in $\mathbb{Q}$, it must contain all of its cluster points.
- If $(x_n)$ is any sequence of the form $\frac{p}{q}+\frac{1}{n}$, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\frac{p}{q}\in[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}\Rightarrow\lim{(x_n)}=\frac{p}{q}$.
- Therefore, every element in $[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ is a cluster point of $[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$.

Is this sufficient? It seems to me to be a bit too easy. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Only its cluster point in what space? In $[0,1]$ it is certainly false, but in $\mathbb Q$ it is certainly true.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: The problem didn't specify, but since it's in a real analysis context, I'm going to assume that it might as well be in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: There has been some ambiguity in the use of the word "countable" recently - in your context does it mean that you can find a bijection with the set of positive integers (the "infinite only" definition) or with a subset of the positive integers (the "finite or countably infinite" definition)?

Comment: There is no such set in $\Bbb R$. Your example works if considered as a subset of $\Bbb Q$, but not as a subset of $\Bbb R$: in $\Bbb R$ every point of $[0,1]$ is a cluster point of the set, so it doesn’t contain all of its cluster points.

Comment: @Mark: In this case it doesn’t matter, at least if we stick to $T_1$-spaces.

Comment: @Mark: Lately? I believe this ambiguity is around for a century or so.

Comment: I don't understand how if $U:=[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$, then $U$ doesn't contain only cluster points. Which points are in $U$ that aren't cluster points?

Comment: @AsafKaragila - referring to posts here.

Comment: @Mark, then recently is from about August 2010, or even July 2010...

Comment: @JoelCornett: The issue is that if we are working in the reals,  $1/\sqrt{2}$ is a cluster point of your $U$ that is not in $U$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Doh. Ok now I get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\{q\in\Bbb Q:0\le q\le 1\}$ is indeed a countable subset of the metric space $\Bbb Q$ that is equal to the set of its cluster points in that space. However, no such set exists in $\Bbb R$. Suppose that $A\subseteq\Bbb R$ is equal to the set of its own cluster points. Then $A$ is closed, since it contains all of its cluster points, and it has no isolated points. A closed set with no isolated points is sometimes called a *perfect* set. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/202054/12042) gives a proof that a perfect set in $\Bbb R$ (or in fact any complete metric space) has cardinality $2^\omega=\mathfrak c$; in particular, it’s uncountable.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct *if* you state your conclusion as

> Let $A = [0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ ($=\{q \in \mathbb{Q}\,:\, 0 \leq q \leq 1\}$) be a subset of the normed space $(\mathbb{Q},|.|)$. Then every $x \in A$ is a cluster point of $A$ and every cluster point $y$ of $A$ lies in $A$.

The important point being that $A$ is considered to be a part of the topological space $\mathbb{Q}$, *not* of $\mathbb{R}$.

You make use of that restriction when you assert that $A$ is closed. $A$ is *not* closed as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ - in $\mathbb{R}$, $\bar{A} = [0,1]$.

Wheter or not your proof is sufficient thus depends on whether you were supposed to find a suitable $A$ in $(\mathbb{R}, |.|)$, or in any topological space of your liking. Note that in the first case, you'll actually have to show that *no* such set exists, since you won't be able to find one.