# Prove: $F$ is countable and closed $\implies F$ has an isolated point.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $F$ be a closed countable non-empty subset of $\Bbb R$. Prove that $F$ has an isolated point.

Comment: Could anyone tell me what is the Negation of the statement?

Comment: [Here](http://pirate.shu.edu/~wachsmut/ira/topo/proofs/pfctuncb.html) is a proof. (A *perfect* set is a closed set with no isolated points, so, requirement, you want to prove a perfect set of reals cannot be countable.)

Comment: @CityOfGod If $F$ has no isolated points then $F$ is not closed or $F$ is not countable.

Comment: @JacobSchlather Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

If X is a countable complete metric space with no isolated points, then each singleton {x} in X is nowhere dense, and so X is of first category in itself. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem)

Answer (score 7):

Hint: Every complete metric space without isolated points is uncountable.

See, [Elementary Real and Complex Analysis](http://books.google.com/books?id=UkQ8ANdjJUcC&pg=PA87&dq=closed%20countable%20isolated%20point&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7KUUUbzmD-nSiwKBnYCQAw&ved=0CDUQ6AEwATgK#v=onepage&q=closed%20countable%20isolated%20point&f=false), P 87.

Answer (score 4):

A *perfect set* is a closed set without isolated points. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/202054/12042) shows that a (non-empty) perfect subset of $\Bbb R$ has $2^\omega=\mathfrak c$ points. In particular, it must be uncountable. Thus, a countable, closed subset of $\Bbb R$ cannot be perfect and must have an isolated point.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to think in another direction.If there is a closed countable non-empty subset of R without any isolated point called F.Lets choose one point of it and then we can say there is a B(x, Δ) which has elements from F.We can then find a sequence of {Δ_x} and in the B_x=B(x, Δ_x) there always are points from F.we can let Δ_x from R,and then we can make a map from R to points in F.Because R is a uncountable set then F is an uncountable set.