# A (further) generalization of Liouville's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

In response to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454221/a-generalization-of-liouvilles-theorem/454256#454256), is it true that for $f:\mathbb{C}-A\to \mathbb{C}$ analytic where $A$ is countable (but not closed!) that $f$ bounded implies $f=c$?

Comment: oops, $A$ should be countable.

Comment: Analytic functions are defined on open sets, so $A$ needs to be closed.

Comment: Thanks! I should have figured it out..

Comment: I think you could have left it as an answer

Comment: Edited and undeleted. My previous answer was for uncountable $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analytic functions are defined on open sets, so $A$ needs to be closed.