# Let $(X,d)$ be a complete metric space. If $X$ has no isolated points then $X$ is uncountable.

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a complete metric space. If $X$ has no isolated points then $X$ is uncountable.

I know that for a Hausdorff and compact general space it is true but, how do I use Baire category in this specific case?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/202054/12042) contains a proof of the stronger result that $|X|$ is at least $2^\omega=\mathfrak{c}$.

Comment: nice @BrianM.Scott!!! Thanks.

Comment: My pleasure! $\,$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, just one questions, is him assuming Hausdorff on this proof, right? To conclude that this intersection is empty?

Comment: It’s a metric space, so it’s automatically Hausdorff.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thanks again.