# Perfect Sets Uncountable in Metric Space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am trying to understand the structure of the neighborhoods constructed, in Rudin's Proof. This question has been touched upon else where but it really does not go into details of the construction process. Is this how Rudin is constructing his neighborhoods?

$$V_1 = \{\textbf{y} \in P : d(\textbf{x}_1, \textbf{y}) < r \}$$ and subsequently,

$$V_n = \{\textbf{y} \in P: d(\textbf{x}_n, \textbf{y}) < \frac{1}{2} d(\textbf{x}_n, \textbf{x}_{n-1})\}$$

Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: This Question was motivated, at least in part, by the earlier post [Proof that a perfect set is uncountable](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201922/proof-that-a-perfect-set-is-uncountable).  Here a clarification of Rudin's proof in *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* is sought.

Comment: Do you know Baire's theorem?

Comment: I am aware of Baire's theorem but nonetheless would like to understand the reasoning here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To recap his construction: $P$ is perfect in a metric space $(X,d)$. We assume $P = \{x_1, x_2, x_3,\ldots \}$. $V_1$ was any neighbourhood of $x_1$, i.e. take some $r_1 > 0$ such that $V_1 = B(x_1, r_1) = \{x \in X: d(x_1, x) < r_1 \}$. We know of course that $V_1 \cap P \neq \emptyset$.

Now we want to construct $V_2$ (an open set) such that

- $\overline{V_2} \subseteq V_1$
- $x_1 \notin V_2$.
- $V_2 \cap P \neq \emptyset$

As $x_1$ is a limit point of $P$, $V_1$ in fact intersects infinitely many points of $P$. Pick $x_i$ where $i > 1$ such that $x_i \in P \cap V_1$. Then as $x_i$ is in $V_1$, for some $s > 0$ we have that the open ball of radius $s$ sits inside $V_1$. We also pick $t = d(x_1, x_i)$. Then set $r_2 = \frac{\min(s,t)}{2}$ and $V_2 = B(x_i, r_2)$. This is open, the factor $\frac{1}{2}$ wrt $s$ ensures that $\overline{V_2} \subseteq V_1$ and being $< t$ ensures that $x_1 \notin V_2$. Also $x_i$ witnesses $V_2 \cap P \neq \emptyset$.

The step from $n$ to $n+1$ is entirely analogous. We can start from any point $x_j$ in $V_n \cap P$, and pick a larger indexed point in the intersection, shrink the radius so that the first and second condition are fulfilled, which can always be done. There is no need for explicit formulae, they only complicate things in this case, I think. The $V_i$ are bals in the whole space, not in $P$ alone, as you suggest. The above is explicit enough.

(As a lemma you can prove that $\overline{B(x,r)} \subseteq \{y: d(x,y) \le r\}$, so that $\overline{B(x,s)} \subseteq B(x,r)$ for any $0 < s < r$ and $x$, which I use above).

Comment: Sure The selection of the points should be from the whole space (my mistake). Other than that what you suggest seems equivalent to what I have. The $$x_i$$ you suggest can be $$x_2$$ for all you care. It is just an index. The idea is that $$x_i \in \{x_1, x_2, x_3, \cdots\}$$, and eventually you have nested balls excluding points $$x_{n-1}$$ which are compact. Leading to the end result.

Comment: The ordering of $P$ is chosen first and is fixed. Otherwise the argument doesn't work.

Comment: @Brandsma, Thank you very much. I think I get it.