# The cardinality of perfect sets

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Do countable perfect sets exist? I know that they are uncountable in R<sup>k</sup>, but what about metric spaces in general?

Comment: I don't really know a lot of Topology, just the basics which are covered in Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A perfect set in a complete metric space has cardinality at least $2^\omega=\mathfrak{c}$; there’s a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/202054/12042). However, the set $[0,1]\cap\Bbb Q$ is a closed subset of the space $\Bbb Q$ of rational numbers that has no isolated points, and it is of course countable, so completeness is required to ensure the larger cardinality.

Comment: @Noah: That was my first thought, but then I wanted to make it clear that *the space itself* wasn’t an aberrant special case.

Comment: So, a perfect set is uncountable if and only if the space is complete?

Comment: @Eternity: It goes only one way: you can have an uncountable perfect set in a space that’s not complete. Take for your space $[0,1]\cup\Bbb Q$, for instance; this is not complete, but $[0,1]$ is an uncountable perfect subset. But completeness rules out anything smaller than $\mathfrak{c}$ as the size of a perfect set.