# Building sequence of balls

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

So I have a metric space $(X,d)$ and a closed subset $P\subset X$, where $P$ has no isolated points, and I want to build a sequence of nested balls in the following way:

- Need to ensure that there are two balls $B_1$ and $B_2$ totally contained in $P$, with $B_1 \cap B_2=\emptyset$.

So it is evident that we can take a radius and two points in $P$ so that that $B_1 \cap B_2=\emptyset$. But how do we ensure that $B_1$ and $B_2$ are totally contained in $P$? I'm interested in the formal construction of such two (closed) balls. Then I know how to construct the rest of the sequence.

Would appreciate some help.

Comment: Let X = R×R and closed P = {0}×R.   P has no isolated points and there are no balls contained in P.

Answer (score 1):

The cantor set is a counter example, as a totally disconnected compact set with no isolated points, considered as a subset of $\mathbb{R} $ with the usual metric.

Comment: So I probably don't even need that ball to be contained in $P$. But then I don't see how such a sequence would necessarily converge in $P$. Edit: No, actually it will, because we are always picking points in $P$ for each subsequent ball.

Comment: @sequence I don't understand, I think there is something missing in your question.

Comment: Sorry, this is a subquestion of my main proof at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2480637/cardinality-of-perfect-set-in-compete-metric-space-is-at-least-continuum

(This is not a duplicate, as I'll soon edit that main post, I just needed to resolve two main issues there).