# Showing Cantor set is uncountable...

Tags: general-topology, compactness, cantor-set

> $C$ is cantor set on $[0,1]$.
>
> [Definition: $A_0$ is the interval $[0,1]$. $$A_n=A_{n-1}-\bigcup_{k=0}^{\infty}\Big(\frac{1+3k}{3^n},\frac{2+3k}{3^n}\Big),\space\space n=1,2,\dots$$
>   The intersection $$C=\bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n$$
>   is called ***Cantor set*** on $[0,1]$]
>
> > (a) Show that $C$ is totally disconnected.
> >
> > (b) Show that $C$ is compact.
> >
> > (c) Show that each set $A_n$ is union of finitely many disjoint closed interval of length $1/3^n$, end show that the end points of this interval lie in $C$.
> >
> > (d) Show that $C$ has no isolated points.
> >
> > (e) Conclude that $C$ is uncountable.

I have no problem of showing the first four (**(a), (b), (c)** and **(d)**) part of the proof. But got stuck at **(e)**. I know this theorem:

> Let $X$ be the nonempty compact Hausdorff space. If $X$ has no isolated points, then $X$ is uncountable.

**How can I show that $C$ is Hausdorff subspace of $[0,1]$?**

Comment: You should show Cantor set is perfect. Then use this:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201922/proof-that-a-perfect-set-is-uncountable

Comment: Thanksssss a lotttttt for the link @GhD I know the solution now for (e).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any subspace of a Hausdorff space is Hausdorff! $[0,1]$ is Hausdorff, so there you go.

Comment: umm, yeah! that should be the case (I know!)... [while writing this comment, just the solution bumped my head]. Thanks a lot, I know the answer now!

Comment: @M.Van  [0,1]  is connected,,,,my question is that       how [0,1]  is  hausdorff ?

Comment: any metric space is hausdorff, [0,1] is a metric space with the absolute value. (to show a metric space is Hausdorff, consider $x,y$ distinct, and let $U_x=B(x, d(x,y)/2))$, $U_y=B(y,d(x,y)/2))$. Now for a point $z$ that is in both sets we'd have $d(x,y) \leq d(x,z)+d(y,z) < d(x,y)$, contradiction, so these open sers are disjoint)