# If $A$ is a non empty subset of the metric space ($\mathbb{R}$,d) and $A$ = $A'$, then $A$ is uncountable.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have to prove this proposition "If $A$ is a non empty subset of the metric space ($\mathbb{R}$,d) and $A$ = $A'$, then $A$ is uncountable. " but I dont know how. Can anybody help me ?

Comment: @Crostul What about the Cantor set?

Comment: Sets with this property are known as perfect sets. The result that perfect sets are uncountable (in a complete metric space) is "famous" if you will: see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201922/proof-that-a-perfect-set-is-uncountable) for some proofs.

Answer (score 0):

The set A cannot be finte as every element in that  finte set is an isolated point.Now if A is countably infinite then A can be written as a countable union of closed sets (since every singleton set is closed).Now A being a closed set of a complete space  is complete.But by Baire category th then at least one closed set must have non -empty interior but singleton set has empty interior .
So A must be uncountable.