# On the Perfect Set

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

When I read and try to understand the uncountability of a perfect set, all of them was in complete metric spaces and $\mathbb{R}^{k}$ taking open intervals and getting contradiction, is there any generalization of the uncountability of perfect sets for any $X$ topological space?  So doesnt it have to be uncountable for any space $X$?

Comment: $\Bbb Q$ is perfect as a subspace of itself

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti thank you so much sir, I think for the completely metrizable spaces, the perfect subsets are uncountable

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201922/proof-that-a-perfect-set-is-uncountable/202054#202054) is a proof for completely metrizable spaces; it actually shows that the cardinality is $2^\omega=\mathfrak{c}$.

Answer (score 0):

It's much more general: it holds for completely metrisable spaces, not just $\Bbb R^n$, e.g. And crowded Baire spaces of course, another large class.

Comment: I got it sir, thank you so much, so how can I start to show that a perfect space is uncountable in completely metrizable space?

Comment: @Woodx essentially the same proof as for $\Bbb R^n$. Assume $A$ is perfect and countable and construct a Cauchy sequence converging to a point not in it, showing it's not closed.

Comment: thank you so much sir

Comment: can we say that the uncountability of Cantor set from this result? so it is perfect and closed so completely metrizable, that is why it is uncountable? @HennoBrandsma

Comment: It's even equinumerous with $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$ so size continuum. @Woodx it's not based on that theorem.