# Prove that there is no continuous bijection $f:\mathbb Q\to K$ of $\mathbb Q$ on a compact metric space $K$.

Tags: analysis

Prove that there is no continuous bijection $f:\mathbb Q\to K$ of $\mathbb Q$ on a compact metric space $K$
Help

Comment: What is $Q?{}{}$

Comment: Q is Rational, sorry

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Consider and enumeration $x_1,x_2,x_3,...$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ and the sets $A_n=f(\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\})\subset K$. These sets must be nowhere dense. Then use [Baire's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem).

Comment: One way is to show that a countable compact metric space must have an isolated point and then use the continuity of $f$ to get a contradiction; the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201922/proof-that-a-perfect-set-is-uncountable) may be helpful.

Comment: Help me plis...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $q_n \rightarrow r$ where $q_n$ are rational and $r$ is irrational. Since $f$ is continuous $f(q_n)$ is cauchy. Since $K$ is compact $f(q_n)$ has a subsequency converging within $K$, Let wlog $f(q_n) \rightarrow z$, $z \in K$. Since $f$ is a bijection, $z=f(c)$. Hence $f(q_n) \rightarrow f(c)$ with $c \in \mathbb{Q}$. So if inverse of $f$ is continuous then $f^{-1}(f(q_n)) \rightarrow f^{-1}(f(c))$. hence $q_n \rightarrow c$ but $c$ is a rational number. hence a contradiction. I am assuming that inverse is also continuous.