# free ultrafilters on $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, lattice-orders, filters, integer-lattices

**Let $\mathbb{N}$ be the set of natural numbers,

  I know the fact that the number of free ultrafilters on $\mathbb{N}$  is uncountable.**

I have two questions:

1.How to construct these uncountable free ultrafilters?
2.Does there exist two disjoint free ultrafilters on $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: (2) is trivial : consider a set $A\in U_1$ and a set $B\in U_2$. Then $A\cup B$ must be in both...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Or even simpler, each contains $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: If I remember correctly (which I'm not at all sure of), if ZF is consistent then so is ZF + every ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$ is principal.  If that's the case, that pretty much eliminates any possibility of giving an explicit construction of a free ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler You are correct.

Comment: @DanielSchepler . And  the axiom of Choice implies there are $2^{2^k}$ many free ultrafilters on a set of cardinal $k\geq \aleph_0,$ so good luck with a "construction" of the set of all of them

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can't have disjoint ultrafilters, since every ultrafilter contains $\mathbb{N}$.

Counting the nonprincipal ultrafilters takes a bit more work.

It's easy to show that there are at *most* $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$-many free ultrafilters on $\mathbb{N}$, since that's how many sets of sets of natural numbers there are, total.

To show that this is sharp, we construct a family $(X_\eta)_{\eta<2^{\aleph_0}}$ of continuum-many sets of natural numbers which are **fully independent**: if $A,B\subseteq 2^{\aleph_0}$ are finite and disjoint, then the family $$\{X_\eta: \eta\in A\}\cup\{\overline{X_\delta}: \delta\in B\}$$ has the finite intersection property.

*This isn't trivial, but is a bit tedious so I'm omitting the details here.*

With such a family in hand, via Zorn's lemma we can show that for any subset $A$ of $2^{\aleph_0}$ there is an ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ containing each $X_\eta$ for $\eta\in A$ and not containing any $X_\delta$ for $\delta\not\in A$. This shows that there are at least $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$-many ultrafilters, and since there are only countably many principal ultrafilters this shows that there are $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$-many free ultrafilters.

Comment: As an addition: Brian wrote out the "tedious" argument you mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/83540/4280).