# Compactness of the associated (Stone) space of an infinite Boolean Algebra.

Tags: general-topology, compactness, boolean-algebra, filters

I am trying to expand my intuition of Boolean algebras and Stone's representation theorem. In particular I am trying to understand why the associated (Stone) space of a Boolean algebra [is always Compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_representation_theorem_for_Boolean_algebras#Stone_spaces) (It is also Hausdorff and Totally Disconnected). For clarity, I want to investigate the special case of a simple infinite Boolean Algebra and identify the apparent flaw in my line of reasoning. (Further generalizations and comments are welcome)

Let $B = \mathcal{P}(\omega)$ be the boolean algebra ordered by inclusion.

Let also $S(B)$ be the set of all utrafilters on $B$.

My understanding is that in our case this would mean that: $S(B) = \lbrace F_i \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\omega) \vert i \in \omega\rbrace$ where each $F_i$ is the principal ultrafilter on $B$ with $\lbrace i \rbrace$ being its minimal element.

We can induce a topology on $S(B)$ generated by the (basic open) sets  $U_b=\lbrace F \in S(B) \vert b \in F \rbrace$

It seems to then follow that $U_{\lbrace i \rbrace} = F_i$ (for all $i \in \omega$) which would mean that all singletons of $S(B)$ are open.

But if that were the case, we simply have that $S(B)$ admits the dicrete topology on an infinite set, and thus it could not be Compact. This would seem to violate the fact that $S(B)$ should always be a Compact, Totally Disconnected, Hausdorff (Stone) space.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE:** It seems that I was missing quite a few ultrafilters in my calculation of $S(B)$. It was not particularly obvious to me as to why there should be any more than just the "obvious" principal ultrafilters. A step in the right direction (at least for me) was to realize that, informally speaking, every ultafilter contains "half" of the elements of the boolean algebra $B$. More formally, for every $b \in B$ and $F \in S(B)$ we have that either $b \in F$ or $\omega \setminus b \in F$ (which immediately means that the basic sets $U_b$ are also closed). The next - far from trivial - step is to observe that one can find several such "dichotomies" which form filters. As a matter of fact, the number of "filter-dichotomies" equals the number of the dichotomies themselves which is rather interesting.

Comment: $S(B)$  contains all ultrafilters, not only the principal ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$S(B)$ contains all countably many fixed ultrafilters $\mathcal{U}_n=\{A \subseteq \omega: n \in A\}$ (for any fixed $n \in \omega$)(also called "principal ultrafilters") but many many more ($2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ many!) non-fixed, free ultrafilters, that have empty intersection, and no common point. These are hard to imagine (you cannot give a constructive example of one) but Zorn's lemma implies that they exist. The fixed ultrafilters as a subspace of $S(B)$  form a countable discrete set. The Stone space is homeomorphic to what topologists call the Cech-Stone (or Stone-Cech) compactification (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification) e.g.) of the integers and the fixed ultrafilters "are" in that compactfication the original integers. The other ultrafilters are the compactifying points we add.

So your picture is incomplete. K.P. has a nice intro to Stone duality [here](https://fa.its.tudelft.nl/~hart/37/onderwijs/old-courses/boole.pdf), as an extra resource.

Comment: What is a "fixed" ultrafilter?

Comment: @NoahSchweber one with non-empty intersection. As opposed to a free ultrafilter. Standard terms, so I thought.

Comment: So "non-fixed" and "free" are synonyms? (Also, I've not seen that term before - do you know a source for it?)

Comment: @NoahSchweber for me, they are.

Comment: @NoahSchweber "Discovering Modern Set Theory I", Just and Weese (p. 135) is the first I could find.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma This is interesting thanks. I was worried I may be missing hidden ultrafilters, which would make sense, especially if the $AC$ is involved. The proof of the compactness of $S(B)$, is it non-trivial also? In general, what is the best intuitive way (if any) to look at $S(B)$ in order to extract all of its topological properties?

Comment: @Pellenthor The compactness isn't that hard, see KP's notes I linked to. You only need to consider covers of $S(B)$ by basic elements, so that brings it back nicely to $B$ (as basic elements are determined by elements of $B$). It's a nice theory, Stone-duality.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Speaking very informally, and upward closure aside, does the $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ number of ultrafilters comes from the fact that for "almost all" elements $b \in \mathcal{P}(\omega)$ we have to make a (binary) choice of whether to include $b$ or $b'$ (its complement) in the ultrafilter? Is this why these extra ultrafilters have an empty intersection and are so hard to imagine?

Comment: @Pellenthor yes, it’s a bit like that, yes. But there is a formal proof of the number on this site too, using independent families. Nice infinite combinatorics.

Comment: @Pellenthor [This nice answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/83540/4280) by Brian W Scott gives an argument as to why there are so many free ultrafilters on an infinite set (works on any size infinite set, not just $\omega$). If you're curious..