# How to force character of ultrafilter be equal to $2^k$?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, filters

Let $k$ be an infinite cardinal. We already know there are exactly $2^{2^k}$ distinct non-principal ultrafilter on $k$.

Here [The set of ultrafilters on an infinite set is uncountable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83526/the-set-of-ultrafilters-on-an-infinite-set-is-uncountable?noredirect=1&lq=1). And proof uses that independent family of cardinality $2^k$.

"Can we force something upon that independent family such that the ultrafilters generated have character $2^k$?"

*But my question for the post is*: Are there exactly $2^{2^k}$ distinct non-principal ultrafilters with character equal to $2^k$?

Definition: Character of ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ is the least cardinality of a filter base of $\mathcal{U}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $I$ be an index set of cardinality $|I|=2^\kappa$.  By Hausdorff's theorem proved in the linked post, there is a collection $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}\subseteq\mathcal{P}(\kappa)$ such that $A_i\ne A_j$ for $i\ne j$ and the $A_i$ generate a free Boolean sub-algebra of $\mathcal{P}(\kappa)$.

Notation: If $S\subseteq\kappa$, $S^\complement:=\kappa\setminus S$.

Let $\mathfrak T=\{T\subseteq I\colon |T|=\aleph_0\}$.  For $T\in\mathfrak T$ define $\mathcal S_T:=\left(\bigcup_{i\in T}A_i^\complement\right)\in\mathcal{P}(\kappa)$.

Claim: The collection $\mathfrak L:=\{A_i\colon i\in I\}\cup\{\mathcal S_T\colon T\in\mathfrak T\}$ has the finite intersection property.

Proof:  Let $F$ be a finite subset of $I$.  Let $J$ be a finite subset of $\mathfrak T$.  For each $T\in J$, since $|T|=\aleph_0$ and $F$ is finite, there is an index $i_T\in T\setminus F$.  By definition of $\mathcal S_T$, $A_{i_T}^\complement\subseteq \mathcal{S}_T$.  Therefore
$$
\left(\bigcap_{f\in F} A_f\right)\cap\left(\bigcap_{T\in J}\mathcal{S}_T\right)\supseteq\left(\bigcap_{f\in F} A_f\right)\cap\left(\bigcap_{T\in J}A_{i_T}^\complement\right)\ne\emptyset\tag{1}
$$
the right hand side being non-empty because $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ generate a free Boolean algebra.  Note that there may be repetitions among the $(i_T)_{T\in J}$, but this is ok, as long as all the $i_T\not\in F$ - which is how they were chosen.  This completes proof of the claim.

Now let $\mathfrak u$ be an ultrafilter such that $\mathfrak L\subseteq\mathfrak u$.  Let $\mathcal B\subseteq \mathfrak u$ be a filter-base.  Since $\mathfrak u\subseteq\mathcal{P}(\kappa)$, it's clear that $|\mathcal B|\le2^\kappa$.  We show that $|\mathcal B|\ge 2^\kappa$.

For $B\in\mathcal B$ let $I_B:=\{i\in I\colon B\subseteq A_i\}$.  We show that $I_B$ is finite.  Assume conversely that $I_B$ is infinite and let $T\subseteq I_B$ such that $|T|=\aleph_0$.  Then $B\subseteq A_i$ for all $i\in T$.  Therefore $B\subseteq \bigcap_{i\in T} A_i$.  Therefore $\bigcap_{i\in T} A_i\in\mathfrak u$.  But $\mathcal S_T=\left(\bigcap_{i\in T} A_i\right)^\complement$ and $S_T\in\mathfrak L\subseteq\mathfrak u$.  This is a contradiction to $\mathfrak u$ being a filter.  Hence $I_B$ is finite.

But now, since $\mathcal B$ is a filter-base, for each $i\in I$ there has to be some $B\in\mathcal B$ such that $B\subseteq A_i$.  Since each $I_B$ is finite, and $|I|=2^\kappa$.  It follows that $|\mathcal B|\ge 2^\kappa$.  This concludes the proof.

We showed how to get one ultrafilter with character $2^\kappa$.  Note however, that in the family $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ we started with, we can complement each member independently and still remain with a family that generates a free Boolean algebra.  Moreover, each ultrafilter obtained by choosing such a combination of $A_i$ or $A_i^\complement$ will be distinct.  Hence there are $2^{2^\kappa}$ distinct ultrafilters with character $2^\kappa$.